# Submit Form When a date is chosen

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Is there a way I can submit a form using the input date type. meaning if a date is chosen, the form gets submitted without any button click?

For **example**,

I have this form:

```html
<form action='ex.php' method='POST'>
  Enter a date: <input type='date' name='date' />
</form>
```

Comment: do it in a javascript
$('#date').blur(function(){$('form').submit();});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If have any datepicker then try below code.

```js
      $('#date1').change(function(){
        console.log('Submiting form');                
        $('#form1').submit();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='ex.php' method='POST' id="form1">
        Enter a date: <input type='date' name='date' id="date1" />
      </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might do the trick - though some validation of the user supplied date might be called for to ensure it is a date that is added & processed.

```
<form action='ex.php' method='POST'>
    Enter a date: <input type='date' name='date' />
</form>


<script>
    var oDate=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]')[0];
    oDate.addEventListener('blur',function(e){
        /* additional date validation here */
        if( oDate.value!='' )oDate.parentNode.submit();
    },false);
</script>
```